# Warning Message Relating To Gas and Infinite Loop

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas

I have the following function that keeps getting a warning relating to high gas costs. Im assuming that it because Im using

> string & uint

but I may be wrong.  I looking for a bit of advice on how to structure this to reduce the possible gas costs, it will only ever be me running this particular function.

```
function AddNewLand(string _geoPoint1, string _geoPoint2, string _geoPoint3, string _geoPoint4, uint _totalinterest, uint _purchasePrice) public {

        if(ownerAddress == msg.sender){

            Land memory _land = Land({
                geoPoint1: _geoPoint1,
                geoPoint2: _geoPoint2,
                geoPoint3: _geoPoint3,
                geoPoint4: _geoPoint4,
                creationTime: uint64(now),
                totalInterest: _totalinterest,
                remainingInterest: _totalinterest,
                purchasePrice: 1000
            });

            uint256 landID = landRegister.push(_land) - 1;

            newLandAdded(landID);

        }else {

            error("Only the contract owner can add a new  of land.");

        }

    }
```

This is the message I am getting

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're accepting strings and storing them. A string can be of arbitrary length, so the gas for this function is unbounded.

That doesn't mean there's a problem, though. When someone actually makes a transaction, they have specific values that they're passing, and they'll get a reasonable gas limit.